# Target types vs return types in java

Tags: java, types, return, target

I was reading the java tutorial from oracle when I stumbled upon this statement:

"Note: It is important to note that the inference algorithm uses only invocation arguments, target types, and possibly an obvious expected return type to infer types. The inference algorithm does not use results from later in the program."

What is the difference between the target type and using the return type to infer the type? Could you please provide an example.

Comment: http://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/25/a-lesser-known-java-8-feature-generalized-target-type-inference/ for Target types and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html for Return types

Comment: and I wonder what "possibly an obvious" means..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this is my understanding.

inferring from the target type:

```
String target = genericMethod();
```

inferring from the return type:

```
String outsideMethod() {
  return genericMethod();
}
```

when `genericMethod` being:

```
T genericMethod() {
  T result = ...
  return T;
}
```